# Strange Problem with Cursor - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

This is a method In my DataBase Class:

```
public Cursor fetchFavTitles() {
    return myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT rowid as _id, title
        FROM table1 JOIN table2 JOIN table3 JOIN table4 JOIN table5 JOIN table6
        WHERE fav = TRUE", null);
}
```

My SQLite database has 6 tables:

1. table1 => rowid, title, content, fav
2. table2 => rowid, title, content, fav
3. table3 => rowid, title, content, fav
4. table4 => rowid, title, content, fav
5. table5 => rowid, title, content, fav
6. table6 => rowid, title, fav

In my activity, I wrote this:

```
Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.fetchFavTitles();
```

and the application forces the close!

Any idea where I'm mistaken ?

**UPDATE**

This is a snapshot of the LogCat, I couldn't understand it, I filtered the output with `android.database`:
[image]

What I am trying to do is getting the `title` (type: TEXT) that have a fav (type: BOOL) with value TRUE From all the tables and display them in one `ListView` (using SimpleCursorAdapter).

Comment: For those who wonder, I NEED to have different tables even if they have the same attributes. So, `merging the database tables` is not an option :)

Comment: What does LogCat say is the exception that's causing the app to close?

Comment: I updated it, please have a look

Comment: Can you explain more @dziobas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding exactly what you're going for, I'm guessing you need to change your query to:

```
SELECT rowid as _id, title
        FROM table1 
        WHERE fav = TRUE
UNION ALL
SELECT rowid as _id, title
        FROM table2
        WHERE fav = TRUE
UNION ALL
SELECT rowid as _id, title
        FROM table3
        WHERE fav = TRUE
UNION ALL   
SELECT rowid as _id, title
        FROM table4 
        WHERE fav = TRUE
UNION ALL       
SELECT rowid as _id, title
        FROM table5 
        WHERE fav = TRUE
UNION ALL       
SELECT rowid as _id, title
        FROM table6 
        WHERE fav = TRUE
```

This will take all the results where 'fav = TRUE' from each of the tables and put them all into one result set. If you don't want duplicates, you can change 'UNION ALL' to 'UNION'. Right now your query is failing because 'SELECT rowid as _id, title' doesn't know which of your tables to pull the 'title' field from.

Comment: Although this seems the solution, but it didn't work ! The LogCat says: `there is no such column fav`. If I remove the WHERE clause from the query, everything is ok. FYI, I added the fav column to the tables after I imported them from an XML file (using SQLite Manager FF Add-on). Does this make a difference ?

Comment: I solved it :-D . It is like you code. You need only to add the `fav` attribute to the SELECT statement. Don't ask me why! Thanks man. Really appreciate your help :)